# Does assigning null remove all event handlers from an object?

Tags: c#, .net, com, delegates, event-handling

I have defined new member in my class

```
protected COMObject.Call call_ = null;
```

This class has the following event handler that I subscribed to

```
call_.Destructed += new COMObject.DestructedEventHandler(CallDestructedEvent);
```

Will setting my member to null as following remove the event handler?

```
call_ = null;
```

or I have to unsubscribed with -=?

Comment: It depends on whether some event handlers still hold a reference to what call_ referenced. If not, the garbage collector will clean it up.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

yes, you should use overloaded `-=` to unsubscribe an event.

simply assigning a reference to `null` will not do that automatically. The object will still be listening to that event.

Comment: Thanks! Can you give me some link of microsoft or another that will verify it?

Comment: @Dor You shouldn't need it - +3 (and possibly more by the time I'm done) is enough for you to know that it's right.  However - this discussion of events from VS2003 days should make it clear... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @AndrasZoltan There have been higher scoring answers than this which were very wrong. Still though, it is correct. The main thing is that the object at `call_` is not set to null, only `call_` which is only one reference to it, there could be others and indeed there are (in the event handlers themselves). It all comes down to the fact that we don't set objects to null, we set references to null.

Comment: It depends a lot on whether the object with the event is going to be collectable in a moment; if it is, it really isn't worth unsubscribing.

Answer (score 9):

You should always unsubscribe your event handlers by -= before setting to null or disposing your objects (simply setting variable to null will not unsubscribe all of the handlers), as given in the MSDN excerpt below:

***To prevent your event handler from being invoked when the event is raised, simply unsubscribe from the event. In order to prevent resource leaks, it is important to unsubscribe from events before you dispose of a subscriber object. Until you unsubscribe from an event, the multicast delegate that underlies the event in the publishing object has a reference to the delegate that encapsulates the subscriber's event handler. As long as the publishing object holds that reference, your subscriber object will not be garbage collected.***

explained at the below link in the `Unsubscribing` section:

[How to: Subscribe to and Unsubscribe from Events (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

More information at:

[Why you should always unscubscribe event handlers](http://davybrion.com/blog/2008/08/why-you-should-always-unscubscribe-event-handlers/)

Comment: In the OP's case, it is fine to just dispose of the object since the object per se is the event publisher. Though to answer the question, doing so does not unsubscribe until it is garbage collected, which can happen because it is the publishing object.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the subtraction assignment operator (-=) to [unsubscribe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) from an event. Only after all subscribers have unsubscribed from an event, the event instance in the publisher class is set to null.

Answer (score -1):

Remove all events, assume the event is an "Action" type:

```
Delegate[] dary = TermCheckScore.GetInvocationList();

if ( dary != null )
{
    foreach ( Delegate del in dary )
    {
        TermCheckScore -= ( Action ) del;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very bad answer; if you have access to `TermCheckScore` as a field-like-event, then you must be **inside** the declaring type; in which case: **just set it to null**. `TermCheckScore = null;` would do everything this does, but much much more efficiently.